# SPARQL query with conditions, lists, etc

Tags: sparql

So I have 3 SPARQL queries that I want to merge:

Query 1

```
PREFIX entity: <http://.../entity/>
PREFIX p: <http://.../prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://.../prop/statement/>
PREFIX pd: <http://.../prop/direct/>
entity:Q276 p:P19 ?statement .
?statement ps:P19 ?next .
?next pd:P18 ?kpa .
```

Query 2

```
PREFIX entity: <http://.../entity/>
PREFIX p: <http://.../prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://.../prop/statement/>
PREFIX pd: <http://.../prop/direct/>
entity:Q276 p:P19 ?statement .
?statement pq:P20 ?nav_rule .
?nav_rule pd:P18 ?kpb .
```

Query 3

```
PREFIX entity: <http://.../entity/>
PREFIX p: <http://.../prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://.../prop/statement/>
entity:Q276 p:P19 ?statement . 
?statement ps:P19 ?next .
?next rdfs:label ?kpc .
```

I want to output `?kpa` and `?kpb` in a list under the variable name `?key_phrase`. In the case that both `?kpa` and `?kpb` are empty or none, then `?key_phrase` should be a list containing `?kpc`. Additionally, `?kpa` and `?kpc` may have multiple values, so extra props if you can include all those values in the same list as well. This new query will be used as a sub-query to a larger sparql query, so I don't think I can use `GROUP-CONCAT` and `ORDER BY`.

**EXAMPLE**

As an example, I want to extract the **AAT ID** (P1014) for every entry that is a subclass of **television program** (Q15416) or **song** (Q7366) or genre **game show** (Q846662). If the **AAT ID** property doesn't exist, then extract the title of the entry instead. All of the values extracted should be listed under the field name **?key_phrase**.

Comment: If this is based on Wikidata, the whole queries don't make sense, thus, it's impossible to give you an answer. `Q276` is the entity https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q276, i.e. the "Eurovision Song Contest". And `P19` and `P20` are the properties "birthPlace" and "deathPlace" respectively. There is no such information in Wikidata.

Comment: If this is not about Wikidata, sample data would be necessary. I also don't understand why use tagged the question with `mysql`

Comment: @AKSW this is not about wikidata. We have our own mediawiki server that we fill with our own data. I can't allow external access to the data, but I can try to provide an illustration. What do you need?

Comment: Some sample data for testing. Without it's always a bit hard to write a working SPARQL query. And what do you mean by "list"? Does it mean simply to get the union of both `kpa` and `kpb` under the same variable `key_phrase`?

Comment: @AKSW I added an example for you. Let me know if you need more.